# Bad practice in php?

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that generates a calendar and then outputs html to display it.

To display it on a page all I need to do is `<?php include('calendar.php'); ?>`.

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to put that sort of thing in a function (or class) rather than an include.

I find that makes it a bit more flexible (especially if you need to start passing arguments to it) and easier to re-use in other places.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is **bad**.

Maybe it's a bit strange to have one file that only does an include... But why not.

Also, it's not MVC and all that *(not that MVC is mandatory anyway)*... But if that's how your application is working, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's bad at all.  I use it for several portions of my web pages to allow easier editing.